# Facing issue saving spark DF on the cloud while using PyArrow: "An error occurred while calling o614"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, visual-studio, pyspark, pyarrow

I am using PyArrow for the faster conversion of Spark DF to Pandas DF and vice versa using command 'spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")'. The final dataset which I want to save on cloud have have millions of records and throughing an error as "An error occurred while calling o614" when I trying to save the converted spark DF. Error Attached

I tried several methods such as disabling PyArrow before saving DF, but nothing is working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.